# CSS Square div with side arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a div that houses an image. This image shows only when an element is hovered over, and therefore I'd like a side arrow to come out of the div pointing to the side (in the direction of the element hovered).

This code generates the square div:

```
 <div id="image-thumbnail-container">
    <img id="image-thumbnail" class="arrow-right">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#image-thumbnail-container {
    display: block,
    position: fixed,
    padding: 4px,
    border-radius: 5px,
}

#image-thumbnail {
    display: block,
    position: fixed,
    border: 1px solid #000,
    padding: 4px,
    border-radius: 5px,
}

.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 17.3px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff0055;
}
```

Here's an example of what I have (this is not what the code generates exactly):

[image]

How to make an arrow and how to make the div is no issue, but is there a way to connect them and have the borders seamless? Such as:

[image]

If this is too much for what it's worth, is there a good way to have the arrow but also a nice background that caters to transparent background images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this.

```css
.arrow{
 position: relative;
 background: #88b7d5;
 border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
}
.arrow:after, .arrow:before {
 left: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-left-color: #88b7d5;
 border-width: 30px;
 margin-top: -30px;
}
.arrow:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-left-color: #c2e1f5;
 border-width: 36px;
 margin-top: -36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```